# MediaElement Source in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

Why does this code produce error

wpf code

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Player" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
```

c# code

```
Player.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Georgi\AppData\Local\VideoPresenter\Content\1.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

The error produced is

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in VideoPresenter.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: looks like `Player` is null. You have to create an instance first. Set some breakpoint at that line and debug it. When it jumps to that line, try hovering your mouse over `Player`, it should be notified as `null`.

Comment: Make sure that your c# code for Player executes after initialization of Player element. It seems like your code fires before InitializeComponent() routine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that The InitializeCompoent() was at the end of the constructor.

```
Player.Source = new Uri(tempPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Player.Play();
InitializeComponent();
```

And the InitializeComponent should be at the very top like this.

```
InitializeComponent();
Player.Source = new Uri(tempPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Player.Play();
```